# SQL Server XML Values Integrity, Consistency, Accuracy

Tags: sql-server, xml

EDIT **The XML value is saved in a XML column in SQL server with the entire transaction**
I have a general question I suppose regarding the integrity of XML values stored in a SQL Server database.

We are working with very imnportant data elements in regards to healthcare. We currently utilize a BizTalk server that parses very complex looped and segmented files for eligibility and BizTalk parses the file, pushes out an XML "value" does some validation and then pushes it to the data tables.

I have a request from a Director of mine to create a report off of those XML values.

So I have trouble doing this for a couple reasons:

1) I would like to understand what exactly the XML has, does this data retain it's integrity regardless of whether we store the value in a table or store it in the XML?

2) Consistency - Will this data be consistent? Or does the fact that we are looking at XML values over and over using XML values to join the existing table to the XML "table" make the consistency an issue?

3) Accuracy - I would like this data to be accurate and consistent. I guess I'm having a hard time trusting that this data is available in the same form the data in a table is...

Am I being too overcautious here? Or are there valid reasons why this would not be a good idea to create reports for external clients?

Let me know if I can provide anything else, I'm looking for high-level comments, code should be somewhat irrelevant other than we have to use a value in the XML to render other values in the XML for linking purposes.

Off the bat I can think that this may not be consistent in that it's not set up like a DB table. No Primary Key, No Duplicate checks, No Indexing, etc...Is this true also?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about comparing a value field in an xml document to a column in a sql table?  Or are you inserting the xml into an xml column in SQL?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz this is the xml in an xml column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this article will answer your concerns: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403385.aspx

If you are treating a row with an xml column as your grain, the database will keep it transactionally consistent.  With the XML type, you can use XML indexes to speed up your queries, which would be an advantage over storing this as varchar(max).  Does this answer your question?